# Converting code python to Java that finds the minimum number of steps to get to 1

Tags: java, python

In this foobar coding question, you're supposed to return the minimum number of steps to get from the given String to the number 1. For example, with the parameter "15", the method would return 4. With the parameter 4, the method would return 2.

I've found the solution in python and was trying to convert to Java, but the Java code does not pass half of the secret tests(I do not know what[enter image description here] the test cases are) while the python code passes the tests. This is the python code:`

```
def solution(n):
    n=int(n)
    res = 0

    while(n!=1):
        if(n%2==0):
            n=n/2
        elif((n==3) or ((n+1)&n) > ((n-1)&(n-2))):
            n-=1
        else:
            n+=1
        res+=1
    return res
```

` code passes are the cases. My question was trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong in my Java code. This is the Java code:

```
public static int solution(String x) {
        int counter = 0;
        int number = Integer.parseInt(x);
        
        while(number != 1) {
            if(number%2 == 0) {
                number = number/2;
            }
            //else if(number == 3 || number%4 == 1) {
            else if((number == 3) || ((number +1)&number) > ((number-1)&(number-2))) {
                number-=1;
            }
            else {
                number+=1;
            }
            counter+=1;
        }       
        return counter;
    }
```

`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code - include the code in your post by selecting, copying and pasting the whole block, and then re-selecting the block and pressing the `{}` button while it's still selected.

Comment: Sorry, new stack overflow user! Just fixed it.

Comment: In Python 3.x, you should use `//` for the division to get an integer rather than floating-point result.

Comment: your python code returning 5 as output when input is '15' can you clarify is it 4 or 5?